# Spring JPA - create N repositories for N databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, sharding, multiple-databases

A have a User @Entity. I have all the necessary credentials for `N` databases in application.properties,
say, in the following format:

```
#First Database Connection
db0.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db0.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users
db0.username=postgres
db0.password=postgres

#Second Database Connection
db1.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db1.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:6432/users
db1.username=postgres
db1.password=postgres
...
#N times
```

All DBs by given credentials exist and have an appropriate User table.

The amount of databases (N) can change with each run.

In my application, I receive the User object and the index of a database to save the object to (number from 0 to N-1).

What is the best way to have an access to all databases in one class, without having N distinct UserRepository objects, each autowired with a Qualifier?

My thoughts were to create a collection (List) of UserRepository, which would get initialized with N dynamically created UserRepositories, based on N DataSources and N TransactionalManagers, from given application.properties, seems like inventing the wheel.